# TortoiseGit revert failed - unable to revert local changes

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When I do some modifications on my local environment like removing files or modifying them and in TortoiseGit I click commit and try to revert the changes I can see and error:

> Revert failed: error: unable to stat just-written file : No such file or directory

Has anyone else experienced this? It seems to be some kind of permissions issues but sometimes this can be fixed by restart of the computer. I would like to find more reliable solution.

Comment: Which version of git are you using?

Comment: Git 2.16.0.windows.2, TortoiseGit 2.5.0.0

Comment: Please update Git for Windows, the 2.16.0.windows.2 contained several bugs regarding stat...

Comment: @MrTux: Please post that as an answer. Updating to 2.16.1.windows.1 resolved this issue for me, and I can guess that it will resolve it for most people that come here in the future.

Comment: @fkorsa Done, answer added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Git for Windows, the 2.16.0.windows.2 contains several bugs regarding stat (based on  faulty fscache implementation; cf. https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/1445).

Git for Windows >= 2.16.1.windows.1 is fixed (cf. release notes https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.1).

PS: For Git >= 2.16 you need at least TortoiseGit 2.5.7.