# git.exe pull error: cannot spawn git: Invalid argument

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have an error exactly as it's on the picture.

[image]

Tried various settings, googled, reinstalled. Git pull doesn't work in TortoiseGit, I can commit and push, though.

I have ssh client in network tab. What else can I try?

Comment: I've got the same problem exactly. Just installed the latest Git and TortoiseGit on a new laptop yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I found that this issue is being tracked at [Git for Windows issue #1481](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1481).

Comment: Issue 1481 will be fixed with the upcoming Git 2.25 (Q1 2020). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364481/6309)

Comment: I'm using 2.39.1.windows.1 and am getting this when fetching a large repo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:**

Git for Windows 2.16.1(4) is out and that should fix this issue: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

---

**Old answer:**

This is a known issue in Git for Windows 2.16.1(2) and 2.16.1(3): https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1481

Only workaround is to use Git for Windows 2.16.1 ([Download](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.1)) (or older; 2.16.0 has other critical issues: [TortoiseGit revert failed - unable to revert local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48446104/3906760)).

Just for the notes, bugreport in TortoiseGit: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/3156

PS: For Git for Windows >= 2.16 you need at least TortoiseGit 2.5.7 (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48457419/3906760).

Answer (score 6):

I rolled back to the version 2.16.0, the problem has disappeared.  [Git for Windows 2.16.0(2)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: That works for me, thanks. The problem appears at 2.16.1.windows.2. I revert it back to 2.16.1.windows.1, and things are fixed.

Comment: Git for Windows 2.16.0 has other critical issues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48446104/3906760

Answer (score 1):

[`git-for-windows/git` issue 1481](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1481) mentioned in 2018 for Git 2.16 is formally fixed with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020).

A Work around has been introduced for an issue where a FD is left open when spawning a child process and is kept open in the child can interfere with the operation in the parent process on Windows.

See [commit 3ba3720](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ba3720b3f187644ac0186a4637898f8e8f85a91) (02 Dec 2019), [commit 4d0375c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d0375ca24f6e317e94705e74c89f33c66c35107) (30 Nov 2019), and [commit ac33519](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac33519ddfa818f420b4ef5a09b4a7b3ac8adeb8), [commit 9a780a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a780a384de21a35866a380247b34442b5ca3bb8), [commit c5a03b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5a03b1e29c69f3f06c8fabd92493edb73469176), [commit eea4a7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eea4a7f4b3620df1b0bd3c1eb1d27e6fd4cb2ff5) (22 Nov 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 55d607d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d607d85b4c22fe2091102ed1eb907ea29b956a), 10 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5a03b1e29c69f3f06c8fabd92493edb73469176): work around incorrect standard handles
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> For some reason, when being called via TortoiseGit the standard handles, or at least what is returned by `_get_osfhandle(`0) for standard input, can take on the value (HANDLE)-2 (which is not a legal value, according to the documentation).
>
> Even if this value is not documented anywhere, `CreateProcess()` seems to work fine without complaints if `hStdInput` set to this value.
>
> In contrast, the upcoming code to restrict which file handles get inherited by spawned processes would result in `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when including such handle values in the list.

Note:

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac33519ddfa818f420b4ef5a09b4a7b3ac8adeb8): restrict file handle inheritance only on Windows 7 and later
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> Turns out that it don't work so well on Vista, see [`git-for-windows/git` issue 1742](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1742)  for details.
>
> According to [Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=8873), it *should* work on Windows Vista and later.
>
> But apparently there are issues on Windows Vista when pipes are involved. Given that Windows Vista is past its end of life (official support ended on April 11th, 2017), let's not spend *too* much time on this issue and just disable the file handle inheritance restriction on any Windows version earlier than Windows 7.
>   To help this, special-case the value (HANDLE)-2 returned by `_get_osfhandle()` and replace it with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,` which will hopefully let the handle inheritance restriction work even when called from TortoiseGit.

That is why there is a [new configuration setting](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac33519ddfa818f420b4ef5a09b4a7b3ac8adeb8#diff-566c950e4fb87f1132745bc5fdb6d3feR562-R567):

> ```
> core.restrictinheritedhandles:
> ```
>
> Windows-only: override whether spawned processes inherit only standard file handles (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) or all handles.
>   Can be `auto`, `true` or `false`. Defaults to `auto`, which means `true` on Windows 7 and later, and `false` on older Windows versions.

---

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a780a384de21a35866a380247b34442b5ca3bb8): spawned processes need to inherit only standard handles
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> By default, `CreateProcess()` does not inherit any open file handles, unless the `bInheritHandles` parameter is set to `TRUE`. Which we do need to set because we need to pass in stdin/stdout/stderr to talk to the child processes.
>   Sadly, this means that all file handles (unless marked via `O_NOINHERIT`) are inherited.
>
> **This lead to problems in [VFS for Git](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit)** (the Virtual File System for Git), where a long-running read-object hook is used to hydrate missing objects, and depending on the circumstances, might only be called *after* Git opened a file handle.
>
> Ideally, we would not open files without `O_NOINHERIT` unless *really* necessary (i.e. when we want to pass the opened file handle as standard handle into a child process), but apparently it is all-too-easy to introduce incorrect `open()` calls: this happened, and prevented updating a file after the read-object hook was started because the hook still held a handle on said file.
>
> Happily, there is a solution: as described in the "[Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873)" there is a way, starting with Windows Vista, that lets us define precisely which handles should be inherited by the child process.
>
> And since we bumped the minimum Windows version for use with Git for Windows to Vista with v2.10.1 (i.e. a *long* time ago), we can use this method. So let's do exactly that.
>
> We need to make sure that the list of handles to inherit does not contain duplicates; Otherwise `CreateProcessW()` would fail with `ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT`.
>
> While at it, stop setting `errno` to `ENOENT` unless it really is the correct value.
>
> Also, fall back to not limiting handle inheritance under certain error conditions (e.g. on Windows 7, which is a lot stricter in what handles you can specify to limit to).

And:

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d0375ca24f6e317e94705e74c89f33c66c35107): do set `errno` correctly when trying to restrict handle inheritance
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>   <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>
>
> In [9a780a384de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a780a384de21a35866a380247b34442b5ca3bb8) ("`mingw`: spawned processes need to inherit only standard handles", 2019-11-22, Git v2.25.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d607d85b4c22fe2091102ed1eb907ea29b956a) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad05a3d8e5a6a06443836b5e40434262d992889a)), we taught the Windows-specific part to restrict which file handles are passed on to the spawned processes.
>
> Since this logic seemed to be a bit fragile across Windows versions (we *still* support Windows Vista in Git for Windows, for example), a fall-back was added to try spawning the process again, this time without restricting which file handles are to be inherited by the spawned process.
>
> In the common case (i.e. when the process could not be spawned for reasons *other* than the file handle inheritance), the fall-back attempt would still fail, of course.
>
> Crucially, one thing we missed in that code path was to set `errno` appropriately.
>
> Let's fix that by making sure that `errno` is set correctly. It even appears that `errno` was set in the *wrong* case previously: `CreateProcessW()` returns non-zero upon success, but `errno` was set only in the non-zero case.
>
> However, when `mingw_spawnvpe()` wants to see whether the file in question is a script, it calls `parse_interpreter()`, which in turn tries to `open()` the file. Obviously, this call fails, and sets `errno` to `ENOENT`, deep inside the call chain started from that test helper.
>
> Instead, we force re-set `errno` at the beginning of the function `mingw_spawnve_fd()`, which *should* be safe given that callers of that function will want to look at `errno` if -1 was returned. And if that `errno` is 0 ("No error"), regression tests like t0061.2 will kick in.