# git pull - cannot spawn plink invalid argument

Tags: git, plink

I had been using tortoisegit for all my git commands.  I decided I should learn how to do it manually.  So I am using the terminal inside IntelliJ Idea for my git commands now.  I was getting some weird error when doing a pull.  So I updated my git to the latest (2.18.0.windows.1).  Now when I do a `git pull` I get a different weird error:

```
error: cannot spawn "C:\plink.exe": Invalid argument
fatal: unable to fork
```

I have the following in my environment variables if that helps.
[image]

I can do a `git status` and that works fine.  Can someone help point me in the right direction to get this working?

Comment: Do you in fact have plink.exe in your C: root directory?  (That would seem like an unusual place to have it installed...)

Comment: yes, that file is there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git.exe pull error: cannot spawn git: Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608113/git-exe-pull-error-cannot-spawn-git-invalid-argument)

Comment: I saw that one.  I am updated to the latest git(2.18) so I don't think that is it.